# IF + AND / OR logic inside of a query

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, google-query-language

below is an example document I have shared:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WuQIqn8DA12R0mNFGMdjJahQ0eNoxKODpSwopk7KoYU/edit#gid=0

My data is simple table:
[image]

I want to do the following:

For starting cell K7 on patient tab
I want to query the call log tab for
two main conditions.

Query select loqic: return rows D,E,F,A when certain conditions are met:

- if text colC equals text in patient tab cell c7 AND col D says "No beds Available" And colI shows time left to calling greater than 0
- OR If not than:
  if col B=cell H3 in patient tab, and Col C= Cell C7 in patient tab

---

Thank you for your help

Comment: And where is the code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: i tried the following:=query('Call log'!1:999,"select Col1,Col4,Col5,Col7 where Col4= 'No Beds Available' and Col3= '"&C28&"' and Col10>0 or Col3='"&C28&"' and Col2= "&$H$3&" ",)

Answer (score 1):

My example could help you.

Suppose you have a small data, like this, columns A:D:
[image]

Then you may use query state with two or more OR conditions, but insert them into parentheses. Sample formula:

`=QUERY({A:D},"select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 where (Col1 < 7 and Col3 = 'c') or (Col2 = 'a' and Col4 > 0)")`

---

To use Col1, Col2, Col3... notation inside query, data must be inside `{}`

Comment: thanks.I think that helps. Is there any way to make it so the query only brings up the first result it finds? or the most recent result?           currently it would show  data for a call made from B Hospital at X time. and B Hospitals at XX time. I only want it to show the most recent call to B hospital at X time.

Comment: Can't answer that in comment. The best way is to post another question.